# Hidden markov models for phoneme recognition in continuous speech

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, hidden-markov-models

I know how to apply hidden Markov model (HMM) when I have an isolated phoneme. I'd just have to create several HMM models (with al least 3 states per model), one for each phoneme, compute forward algorithm on all of them and see which one has the greatest probability.

But now I have a continuous speech database, phoneme labeled at each frame (TIMIT). How could I train a HMM so it can recognize phonemes in continuous speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: For *continuous* speech recognition you connect your phoneme models into a large HMM using auxiliary silence models.

First of all, you can train models on isolated phonemes and apply them to continuous speech. For instance, you can chunk your training audio according to the existing labels.

At the recognition step, applying Viterbi decoding (the most likely sequence of hidden states) to a combined model is equivalent to recognition of the sequence of phonemes. For more details you can study the corresponding [chapter](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/Speech/docs/HTKBook/node9.html) from HTK book.

To *train* HMMs on continuous data you also do a similar trick: combine single phoneme models into a large model for the whole underlying sentence. The training framework will find the best alignment between the model's states and the audio. Again, [HTK book](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/Speech/docs/HTKBook/node29.html) provides a nice tutorial on this.

[Phoneme Recognition on the TIMIT Database](https://www.intechopen.com/books/speech-technologies/phoneme-recognition-on-the-timit-database/) provides a complete overview of the methods with a lot of references to papers. For instance, [this classical article](http://shelf2.library.cmu.edu/Tech/18073818.pdf) describes a basic method for context-independent phoneme recognition.

Comment: Ok, I see. So these silence models don't have to be trained alone right?

Comment: Normally, every single phoneme model (including silence) is trained together with others on complete sentence audio. Chunking utterances into phonemes can be very time and space consuming and not needed indeed.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but in the training step when you said "combine single phoneme models into a large model for the whole underlying sentence." you just have the phoneme models untrained?

Comment: They are initially not trained, but initialized with global mean and variance values estimated before the actual training starts. See the 'Creating Flat Start Monophones' section: http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/Speech/docs/HTKBook/node29.html